# How can I use AWS EBS Volumes with bare metal Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ebs, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I am using a manually created Kubernetes Cluster (using `kubeadm`) deployed on AWS ec2 instances (manually created ec2 instances). I want to use AWS EBS volumes for Kubernetes persistent volume. How can I use AWS EBS volumes within Kubernetes cluster for persistent volumes?

Cluster details:

- `kubectl` veresion: 1.19
- `kubeadm` veresion: 1.19

Comment: Basic functionality is already included in k8s, but you might want to CSI and the EBS CSI.

Comment: You can install the CSI driver: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver and use it to dynamically provision EBS volumes for the PVC resources you create.

Comment: I have tried EBS CSI too. but no hope

Comment: @Suresh Well, it is the standard solution for EBS provisioning. The other choice is to manually attach a large-enough EBS devices to each of bare metal nodes and then install open-ebs to provision volumes ( created and deleted as directories in device mount path on the same node) https://docs.openebs.io/docs/next/localpv.html

Comment: Hi @Suresh, which exactly problem you have with EBS CSI? Could you please paste some logs / steps that you followed?

Answer (score 1):

Posted community wiki for better visibility with general solution as there are no further details / logs provided. Feel free to expand it.

---

The official supported way to mount [Amazon Elastic Block Store](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) as [Kubernetes volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) on the self-managed Kubernetes cluster running on AWS is to use [`awsElasticBlockStore`volume type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#awselasticblockstore).

To manage the lifecycle of Amazon EBS volumes on the self-managed Kubernetes cluster running on AWS please install [Amazon Elastic Block Store Container Storage Interface Driver](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver).